# Can't HTTP request on Android Pie

Tags: android, http, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

Hy, I have some issue on HTTP request on ionic, I used ionic v1. I make simpel request with XMLHttp it work on OS Oreo and nether but on Pie it not run. My cie like this :

```
var latlng = new XMLHttpRequest();
latlng.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
   }
};
latlng.open("GET", "http://MYDOMAIN/coba.php", true);
latlng.send();
```

Can someone give me some suggestion or can explain my issue, Thanks

Comment: Did you get any error ? Check logs for Error and add it with question .

Answer (score 0):

Your request URL is HTTP, not HTTPS. Android P uses HTTPS by default. What this means is that if you are using unencrypted HTTP requests in your app, the app will work fine in all versions of Android except P version.

To resolve this you just need to create a network_security_config file in the xml folder and then include it in the manifest in the following manner.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The network_security_config file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">nikit19.github.io</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Here you can simply mention the domain name of your server or all the domain names that are using HTTP.

For more detail visit [link](https://medium.com/mindorks/my-network-requests-are-not-working-in-android-pie-7c7a31e33330)

Hope this will help you.